NextJs logs not showing up in K8S pod
I am using Next 14 (app router).
I have a route such as app/api/route.js
There are some console.log() statements in the route.js.
when checking pod logs, I cannot see any console.log() statements there.
I can only see logs that says application has started as image below.
Why can't I see any console.logs in the server. This is a server component so the logs should be in the pod logs.
however, I can see the logs that are written in the client side in the browser.


Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Given your description it sounds like the server component is just sending code over to the end user's browser, and the actual application (and the console.log() statements) is running in the browser.  The server won't be able to see the client-side logs.

because you are running your code on the client side by using "use client" you can see the console.log()  statement on the server side you just need to remove "use client", I hope this is useful for you.

So my server code is under app/api/route.js and this is server code. There is no “use client” on top of this file.

are you sure you are not use any component in your code that is contain "use client"

can you add code for more details?
